# URL has Id specified, but still getting the parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, shopify, asp.net-web-api-routing

I understand what this error is stating and the typical cause, but in this case, I'm not sure why it is being thrown.

Here's the full error message:

> System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null
>   entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]
>   AppUninstalled(Int32)' in
>   'Storefront.Controllers.ShopifyWebhooksController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

The url being called against my app is: `/storefront/wh/AppUninstalled/88564`. So it is passing the Id as int.

Here's the route definition:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Storefront_default",
        "Storefront/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Here's the action signature that is being called: `public async Task<string> AppUninstalled(int id)`

Now when I test this locally or against my staging server using Postman, I don't get this error. But when Shopify calls it, I do get the error. And I can verify via the Elmah error generated, that the url that was called is just as I posted above, with the trailing Id value.

**UPDATE: 1**

I also tried having shopify call the url with the id explicitly named: `/storefront/wh/AppUninstalled?id=88564` but get the same error.

Could it be something in the encoding that MVC can't convert the id to an int?

**UPDATE 2**

This works, but it doesn't explain why the above did not work.

Changing the action method in MVC to:  `public async Task<string> AppUninstalled(string strId)`

Changing the Shopify call back url to: `/storefront/wh/AppUninstalled?strId=88564`

Comment: did you try int id ? not int Id (capital I)

Comment: Did you try `public async Task<string> AppUninstalled(int? id)` ?

Comment: did you call /storefront/wh/AppUninstalled/88564 by ajax or in navbar?

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov - I tried that....still got the error...though it did recognize I changed it: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' f`

Comment: @HienNguyen - with the Postman app, using a post as this method is decorated with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @ChadRichardson This action is only available through a POST ??

Comment: @Spotted yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that since `id` is declared optional in `MapRoute` you should declare your action like this:

```
public async Task<string> AppUninstalled(int? id)
```

And check if `id` has a value and take action if not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Spotted, but I don't think that is the case. The optional is stating that some actions may not have an Id...i.e. the Index action does not, but the Edit does. I use this same route configuration in 15 different Areas within out site with actions that use non-nullable int parameters and it has been working fine for years. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ChadRichardson Ok but did you try ? I strongly suspect that this _could_ work because it worked when you changed the parameter type to `string`, which is coincidently a nullable type. However, it will explain in nothing why this would work.

Comment: @ChadRichardson You said it has been working for years. Which change did you recently to make this error happen ? Modifying/adding a route ? Updating an aspnet package ? Adding a new controller and/or action ? Adding a new area ? Anything else that come to your mind ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `RouteParameter.Optional` and    `MapHttpRoute` instead of    `UrlParameter.Optional`  and  `MapRoute`

```
   routes.MapHttpRoute( // <-- this
                name: "Storefront_default",
                routeTemplate: "Storefront/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {action ="Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional // <-- this 
});
```

Comment: `context` does not have a `MapHttpRoute`. I did make the change to `RouteParameter.Optional` and am testing now. Take a look at my update too, I tried explicitly adding the parameter querystring...to no avail.